# Passing long string in javascript argument

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I have a php page which i have array of values with long values.

I gave to pass this array in a javascript function like this

$canswer is an array 
I am imploding that and passing as arguments as follows,

```
$cans=implode(',',$canswer);
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='q1' id='1' onclick=\"save_answer('1','$cans')\">";
```

This code is working for short values in array.When I have long values in array,onclick is not working.When I tried to see view source,I saw the array values cut off in the page.

I have tried the following code to give quotes for each values.But this also not works.

```
$correctanswer1="'" . implode("','", $correctanswer) . "'";echo $correctanswer1;
```

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: May be due to bad escaping...

Comment: Can you post your `save_answer` function?

Comment: use json encode and decode

Answer (score 1):

You could save the array of values as a javascript string on the page, then call the string in the `onclick` attribute.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    cans_string = '<?php echo implode(',',$canswer); ?>';
</script>

<input type="checkbox" name="q1" id="1" onclick="save_answer('1',cans_string)">
```

Comment: I am passing the argument in checkbox onclick in php.How this is possible

Comment: You can run php on just some parts of your page. Your entire page can be html, with one section containing `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 0):

1. explore the array before to add it as parameter (print_r?)
2. extract javascript function into an javascript file
3. use jason to pass array as a parameter

Hope this will solve the problem

Comment: Can't understand what you are saying

Comment: well, because you cannot see the array in the page you should use print_r to check what is cumming as parameter and why there are missing parts. Javascript is recommended to be places in separate files and function should be properly attached to handler (onclick in your case). Because array is hard to pass as an array object between server and client it is better to use JSON instead. Hope now is clearer than before, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not escaping some of the special characters in your output. Run your output through `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to eliminate characters that will break your HTML or javascript.

```
$cans=htmlentities(implode(',',$canswer), ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='q1' id='1' onclick=\"save_answer('1','$cans')\">";
```

Pay attention to where your output is breaking, and what characters could be breaking it.